# Как ограничить доступ к роуту, а разрешить только после сабмита формы

Tags: javascript, reactjs, form, react-router, react-router-dom

По пути `\src\client\app.js` у меня есть файл с роутами

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {

        };
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <Router history={customHistory}>
                <div>
                        <Header/>
                        <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage}/>
                        {/* {routes.map(route => 
                        <Route exact path={route} component={UpgradePage} key={route}/> 
                        )} */}
                        <Route exact path="/how-to-upgrade" component={UpgradePage}/>
                        <Route exact path="/about-us" component={AboutUsPage} />
                        <Route path="/thank-you" component={ThankYou} />
                        <Route path="*" component={NotFound} status={404}/>
                        </Switch>
                        <Footer/>                        
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

По пути `\src\client\components\ContactUs\ContactUs.js`
есть компонент, что на основной странице лендинга, отрендеривает контактную форму
[для удобства оставлю код компонента формы тут](https://codepen.io/annbin/pen/QWLroYv)

Проблема в том, что я не могу никак сделать ограничение для входа на роут без сабмита формы, то есть юзер должен перейти на компонент по роуту 
`<PrivateRoute path="/thank-you" component={ThankYou} />`
только когда он успешно отправит форму, а иначе его будет редиректить на
этот компонент `<Route path="*" component={NotFound} status={404}/>`

помогите плиз реализовать такой функционал

Comment: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow

Comment: @ThisMan я пробовала уже это, пыталась переделать этот пример и ничего не вышло, постоянно возникали ошибки, да и способ сделан в одном файле где порядок зависит от того как код написан, у меня 2 файла и есть проблема в том, что я не знаю куда какую часть кода впихнуть, вот и попросила помощи тут

Comment: у реакт роутера есть хуки, которые выполняются перед каждым роутом. Можно засунуть функцию авторизации туда и если что редиректить на страницу 404

Comment: @ThisMan у меня не авторизация, ничего с тем что б юзер логинился нету, нужна просто проверка на то, была ли отправлена контактная форма или нет

Answer (score 1):

Заведите просто HOC, который будет добавлять компоненту проверку на какое-то действие: авторизация, заполнение формы - не важно. И используйте его для всех роутеров, которые нужны

https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-router-basic-rnec4?fontsize=14

```
let hasUserAccess = false;

function privateRoute(Component) {
  return function(props) {
    if (!hasUserAccess) {
      return <Page404 />;
    }
    return <Component {...props} />;
  };
}
```

И использовать вот так:

```
<Route path="/path" component={privateRoute(Component)} />
```

**Полезные ссылки**: 
[`route-render-methods`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-render-methods) 
[`что такое HOC`](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)

Comment: Стало даже сложнее
первый код, это отдельный файл должен быть или это в файле с роутами нужно оставить? или в компоненте формы

Comment: эммм, что сложного? Где у вас хранится информация, что пользователь заполнил форму? если в `redux`, тогда вообще смотрите в сторону `react-router-redux`, если в каком-то самостоятельном стейте, тогда туда и поместите функцию приватности а в `App.js` импортируйте ее

Comment: по ссылке есть полный пример, как видите функция должна иметь доступ к тому месту, где определяется, что пользователь сделал действие. А потом импортируйте функцию в нужные места и все

Comment: по ссылке на кодпен которая в вопросе есть компонент формы, то там нету проверки на то заполнена форма или нет, там просто проверка в виде успешной или афейленой отправки, в которой я и меняю состояние того, можно ли редиректить на тот роут `if (response.data.msg === 'success')`

Comment: проверка на заполненость идет через валидатор, который не пускает к отправке без данных